# org.json.JSONException when get image from mysql

Tags: android, mysql, json

Hi im having problems calling my image on server mysql inside android aplication, i looks is a problem decoding the image, i have trying many ways but not found a solution. here is the log error:

`09-27 05:08:56.588: W/System.err(3388): org.json.JSONException: Value {"empresas":[{"img_empresa":"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
        09-27 05:08:56.617: I/Choreographer(3388): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
        09-27 05:08:57.257: W/System.err(3388):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        09-27 05:08:57.257: W/System.err(3388):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
        09-27 05:08:57.328: W/System.err(3388):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
        09-27 05:08:57.328: W/System.err(3388):     at com.siont.divi.HomeFragment$AsyncListViewLoader.doInBackground(HomeFragment.java:126)
        09-27 05:08:57.367: W/System.err(3388):     at com.siont.divi.HomeFragment$AsyncListViewLoader.doInBackground(HomeFragment.java:1)
        09-27 05:08:57.457: W/System.err(3388):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        09-27 05:08:57.457: W/System.err(3388):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        09-27 05:08:57.507: W/System.err(3388):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        09-27 05:08:57.547: W/System.err(3388):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        09-27 05:08:57.557: W/System.err(3388):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        09-27 05:08:57.557: W/System.err(3388):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)`

the image is saved in table like blob and this is the php code with json, it works in webserver

```
` $con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 


$empresas['empresas'] = array();

if( $con )  
{  
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot connect to DB");  

  $res = mysql_query('select id_empresa, nom_empresa, img_empresa from empresas');

  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) {
    array_push($empresas['empresas'], array('id_empresa' => $row['id_empresa'], 'nom_empresa' => $row['nom_empresa'], 'img_empresa' => base64_encode($row['img_empresa'])));
  }
  mysql_free_result($res);
  mysql_close($con);
}

echo json_encode($empresas); `
```

this is the asynctask

```
` private class AsyncListViewLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Empresa>> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());    
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Empresa> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            empAdapter.setItemList(result);
            empAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //ListDrawer();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {     
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Cargando Empresas...");
            dialog.show();          
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Empresa> doInBackground(String... params) {
            List<Empresa> result = new ArrayList<Empresa>();

            try {
                URL u = new URL(params[0]);

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                // Read the stream
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                while ( is.read(b) != -1)
                    baos.write(b);

                String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);
                for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    result.add(convertEmpresa(arr.getJSONObject(i)));
                }

                return result;
            }
            catch(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private Empresa convertEmpresa(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {           

            Empresa emp = new Empresa(obj.getInt("id_empresa"), obj.getString("nom_empresa"));
            emp.setData(obj.getString("img_empresa"));

            return convertEmpresa(obj);
        }

    } `
```

here i define the class Empresa

` public class Empresa implements Serializable {

```
    private int id_empresa;
    private String nom_empresa;
    private String data;
    private Bitmap img_empresa;

    public Empresa(int id_empresa, String nom_empresa){
        super();
        this.id_empresa = id_empresa;
        this.nom_empresa = nom_empresa;
    }

public String getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    try {   
      byte[] byteData = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
      this.img_empresa = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( byteData, 0, byteData.length);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public Bitmap getImg_empresa() {
    return img_empresa;
  }

  public int getId_empresa() {
    return id_empresa;
}

public void setId_empresa(int id_empresa) {
    this.id_empresa = id_empresa;
}

public String getNom_empresa() {
    return nom_empresa;
}

public void setNom_empresa(String nom_empresa) {
    this.nom_empresa = nom_empresa;
}

@Override
  public String toString(){
        return this.id_empresa+this.nom_empresa+this.data;
    }

} `
```

Im stuck i have tried different ways to solve my problem but dont get it, any help will really great! thanks a lot

Comment: JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp); and your json file contailns a json object that contains a JSON array.. Could it be it? There's just too much code here

Comment: hi Loma you are right and the error is in the homefragment activity lane 126, you have any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: i solve part of my problem i can call the string and int datas but i cant get the image here is what i have <code> private Empresa convertEmpresa(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {   
   
   int id = obj.getInt("id_empresa");
   String name = obj.getString("nom_empresa");
   
   String img = obj.getString("img_empresa");
   
   return new Empresa(id, name, img);
  } <code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log is telling you whats going on here:

```
 09-27 05:08:57.257: W/System.err(3388):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
```

Type missmatch is saying you told me im gonna get a jsonarray, but i got a jsonboject and i dont know what to do with it!

The problem is in this line:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);
```

You are trying to pull out a json array from something that is a JSON object - your file contailns a json object, that contains a JSON array.. 
If you are not sure what is the difference read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) and pay attentiton to brackets :)

This will solve your problem:

```
String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(JSONResp);
                JSONArray arr = jobj.get("empresas");
                for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                   //get whatever you want to get from your array
                        JSONObject jobj = arr.get(i);

                }
```

Comment: thanks that solve the problem but i cant get the image, i know that need to call the setData <code>private Empresa convertEmpresa(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {   
   
   int id = obj.getInt("id_empresa");
   String name = obj.getString("nom_empresa");   
   convertEmpresa.setData(obj.getString("img_empresa"));
   
   return new Empresa(id, name);
   
  }<code> i have a red line in convertEmpresa.setData,  any idea?

Comment: okay you have a red line, but what is the error? Errors that Eclipse(or any other IDE) shows can point you to why is this line red(not correct)..

Comment: convertEmpresa cannot be resolved, thats the error Loma.